# Why isn't my function invoked? I don't understand why a declaration is expected

Tags: c, gnu

Hello folks out there,

this is my code:

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "db_typedefs.h"
#include "operations.h"
int main(){
    printf("Text\n");
    int f = 3;
    void add_mini(3);
}
```

#### operations.h

```
#ifndef ADD_OPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define ADD_OPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED

void add_mini(int flag);
#endif // ADD_OPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

#### operations.c

```
void add_mini(int flag)
{
    int rc;
    rc = flag;
    printf("%i\n", rc);
}
```

Operations.c has also libraries included similar to main.c.

### Compiler Error

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
```

regarding to void add_mini(3)

It seems like I'm unable to pass a simple integer value. While debugging it's even skipping the add_mini line.
Do you have any idea what's going on?

---

The whole code is embedded in a larger query to determine typed orders but this works fine. I just can't pass this simple integer value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
void add_mini(3);
```

the compiler thinks it is a function declaration, not a function call. The argument `3` is not valid for a function declaration. Hence, the compiler complains.

Remove the `void` part to call the function.

```
int main(){
    printf("Text\n");
    int f = 3;
    add_mini(3);
}
```

or, since you have initialized `f` to `3`,

```
int main(){
    printf("Text\n");
    int f = 3;
    add_mini(f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the function like so: `add_mini(3);` rather than `void add_mini(3);`

Comment: ...or even `add_mini(f);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the word void for calling `add_mini` from main.c :

```
add_mini(3);
```

Or

```
(void)add_mini(3);
```